# Integrate Android Login with ASP.NET website

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I am embarking on the creation of an Android application (and subsequently iOS, if it makes a difference to the answer) as a mobile version of an existing website. I would like users on the website to be able to log into the mobile version and vice versa.

The website is written in ASP.NET MVC and I was planning to use ASP.NET Web API (accepting and returning xml/json) to submit/retrieve necessary data for the application. The website uses a .NET membershipprovider for authentication.

Can I reuse my existing authentication mechanisms to authenticate android users and enable them to log into the Android App? If so, what is the suggested method of doing so?
Thanks,
JP

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want to create an android version and later an iOS version too, you should consider using a web based framework for mobiles. Take a look at [jQuery mobile](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/)

These are not for everyone. They work great for webapps. But are not as fast as native apps.

Your native application would only be a wrapper then that presents the mobile version of you site in a web view. Both android and iOS have support for this.

Would save you a lot of code rewrite and maintenance if it works for you.

If you do want to create a native app, you can definitely create a WebAPI based login and use that from an android client.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We have already created a jQuery mobile version of the site, but plan on native applications for major platforms.